# What is $X^*$, the topological dual of the space $X:=AC[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, optimal-control

Let $X = AC[0,1]$ be the space of all [absolutely continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity) functions from  $[0, 1]$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$, with $W^{1,1}$ norm that is

$$   \|f\| = \int_{0}^{1} |f(t)| \; dt +   \int_{0}^{1} |f'(t) | \; dt        $$

My question is that: What is $X^*$, the dual of the space $AC[0,1]$?

I searched in the internet I only found the dual of $W^{p,1}$ with $p > 1$ !

Comment: Is $X$ a Banach space when equipped with the $W^{1,1}$ norm?

Comment: @kkc: Yes, it is.  As I note below, it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n \oplus L^1([0,1];\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first consider $n=1$.  Then $X = AC([0,1]; \mathbb{R}^1)$ is isomorphic as a normed space to $\mathbb{R} \oplus L^1([0,1])$; one possible isomorphism is $Tf = (f(0), f')$.  Therefore $X^*$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R} \oplus L^\infty([0,1])$ via the adjoint of this isomorphism.  In other words, every continuous linear functional $\ell$ on $X$ can be uniquely written in the form $\ell f = a f(0) + \int_0^1 h(t) f'(t)\,dt$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$, $h \in L^\infty([0,1])$.

(I mean "isomorphism" here in the sense of "linear homeomorphism".  My map $T$ is not an isometry.)

A few hints in verifying that $T$ is an isomorphism:

- $(T^{-1}(c,g))(x) = c + \int_0^x g(t)\,dt$
- To see that the map $X \ni f \mapsto f(0) \in \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, use the identity $f(0) = \int_0^1 f(t)\,dt - \int_0^1 \int_0^x f'(t)\,dt\,dx$.

For the general case, you can note that $AC([0,1]; \mathbb{R}^n)$ is isomorphic to the direct sum of $n$ copies of $AC([0,1]; \mathbb{R}^1)$ by taking components.  This leads to the conclusion that its dual is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n \oplus L^\infty([0,1]; \mathbb{R}^n)$.

Comment: Based this can we say that two the norms; $\|f(0)\| + \int_{0}^{1} \| f' (t) \| \; dt$ and $ \int_{0}^{1} |f(t)| \; dt +   \int_{0}^{1} |f'(t) | \; dt$ are equivalent ?

Comment: @Redshoes: Yes, they are equivalent, and you can prove this directly using a variant of the identity in the second bullet point.

Comment: Thank You. I've seen  that the norm $\| f \|_{L^1} + \| f' \|_{L^1}$ is used in general sobelov space $W^{1,1} (\Omega)$ when $\Omega$ is open set. Here I used $\Omega=[0,1]$ which is not closed,  so based what you proved, the norm $\| f\|_{L^1} + \| f' \|_{L^1}$  still works for at least compact interval?

Comment: Right.  In the special case of one dimension, having an open or a closed interval makes no difference: an absolutely continuous function on an open interval has a unique continuous extension to the closed interval.